# Setting the datasource of the child band in UltraGrid

Tags: infragistics

I have an UltraGrid in my Windows Form Application and it has to have two bands. I was able to setup the Parent Band with no problem by using the code below:

```
        Try
            con.Open()
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT o.OJTID, o.Surname + ', ' + o.FirstName + ' ' + o.MiddleName AS FullName, t.TotalGrade FROM tblOJTs o INNER JOIN tblTGrades t ON o.OJTID = t.OJTID", con)
            da.Fill(ds, "tblOGrades")
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error connecting to databe.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            con.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.ViewStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ViewStyle.MultiBand
        UltraGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tblOGrades")
```

The thing now is, I dont know how to set the datasource of the Child Band. I dont encounter such problem with UltraWebGrid because of the Hierarchical DataSource feature but I think its not available for WinForms. I know you guys will help thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fill another DataTable in your DataSet with the data related to the first table. After that, you should define the relation between the two datables and finally set the DataSource of the UltraWinGrid  to the DataSet itself instead of the single DataTable.

For example:

```
con.Open()
da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT o.OJTID, o.Surname ....", con)
da.Fill(ds, "tblOGrades")
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT .related data....", con)
da.Fill(ds, "tblRelated")
ds.Relations.Add("Grades_Relation", _
   ds.Tables("tblOGrades").Columns("OJTID"), _
   ds.Tables("tblRelated").Columns("relatedID"))
con.Close()

....

UltraGrid1.DataSource = ds
```

Comment: Hello Steve, your answer works great thank you. Will mark this as an acceptable answer now. Kudos

Comment: Very helpful, just want to add that for me I add to use brackets not parentheses when qualifying the columns:
ds.Relations.Add(ds.Tables["mytable1"].Columns["mycol"],...

Comment: That's ok, the OP code was VB.NET so the parentheses. C# needs square brackets.